# Make persistent entity immutable based on its field value

Tags: hibernate, immutability, interceptor

We use java + hibernate in our application. One table has a column to indicate the record is immutable or mutable. The records with immutable flag are inserted to the table using SQl by application deployment process.

The application uses hibernate session to save/delete/update entities to/from the table.  We would like hibernate will do nothing for a record with the flag of immutable.

How to mark a record immutable based on its field value?
How to prevent hibernate update/save/delete an entity based on its field value?

We have tried to use hibernate interceptor and failed:

1. throws exception from onSave, onDelete: the transaction rolled back
2. null out entity when it has the immutable flag: the entity got deleted.

Also wanted to use Java bean setter, but it can stop updating, but can not prevent deletion. We do not want to put hacky code in setters and also in service to achieve it. We would like to find a way to use JPA/Hibernate provided functionalities to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `update` and `delete` statements used for the entity with `@SQLUpdate` and `@SQLDelete` by including a where clause predicate on the column. Something like this:

```java
@Entity
@SQLUpdate(sql = "update my_entity set col1=?,col2=? where id=? and immutable=false", check = COUNT)
@SQLDelete(sql = "delete from my_entity where id=? and immutable=false", check = COUNT)
public class MyEntity {
    ...
}
```